# Using same workspace for multiple applications

Tags: android, android-studio, properties-file

I've made an application where, according to the backend configurations, the application behaves differently. So using the same code, I can build different APKs according to the requirement for that specific application **

But each time I have to build an APK, I have to change a particular set of things(application id, server endpoint, app icon, firebase id, crashlytics id, etc). I want to maintain one workspace, and according to the properties file pick the appropriate resources.

List of things that need to be changed according application :

1. application id
2. server endpoint
3. app icon
4. firebase id
5. crashlytics id
6. Mics image (drawable) resources

How can I manage this without creating separate workspaces and branches to maintain the code for multiple applications??

** Its like a framework, where you can change a few things(application id, server endpoint, app icon, firebase id, crashlytics id, etc) and build a new application.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **product flavors** for that. Please have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors).

Each flavor can specify its own configuration like e.g. its application or specify its own resources like drawables.